# vertically centering things in responsive divs

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have a background image that I'm maintaining its aspect ratio like so ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/3gyc4atn/)):

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 703px;
}

.greeting {
    background-image: url('ANIV_ARG_CELEB.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:left;
    position: relative;
        min-width: 300px;
        min-height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 34.6% 0 0 0;
}


<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="greeting texttop" style="background-image: url('top/ANIV_BOW.jpg');">
          <div class="message">
               <form action="" method="post">
                    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                </form>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This works great only now I'm trying to place a textbox within the div so that it stays at the top of the image on all devices.

This setup works well for mobile, placing the textbox at the top, however as the screen size grows the textbox becomes lower and lower.

Perhaps this can't be done in a fluid form and needs media queries?

Comment: I just don't get what you're after for, the fiddle doesn't look correct even if you replace the textarea with a text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to move the textbox in relative to the image position. The image can be transformed to Landscape or portrait based on vertical or horizontal resize of the window. This is not possible using just css. This can be solved using javascript if you know the dimensions of the Image.

In your case, the image dimensions are `774 X 543`. So, here is the solution for that:

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var w = 774;
    var h = 543;

    function setMessageBox() {
        var greeting = $('.greeting');
        var height = greeting.height();
        var width = greeting.width();
        console.log(height);
        if (width > (w / h) * height) {
            $('.greeting.texttop .message').css('top', '0px');
        } else {
            var vHeight = (h * width) / w;
            var topSpace = (height - vHeight) / 2;
            $('.greeting.texttop .message').css('top', topSpace.toFixed(2) + 'px');
        }
    }
    setMessageBox();
    window.onresize = setMessageBox;
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/3gyc4atn/16/)**

Comment: Then aspect ratio is off...Maybe I should have used an image with a border to show its borders.

Comment: @BenRacicot Yeah I understand now.. your post is unclear. I will try here.

Comment: Very clever JS @Mr_Green! Although I can't seem to get it to work within the fiddle. Also, you don't think it can be done with just CSS?

Comment: @BenRacicot actually, I am still trying.. I thought to update you when I complete it.. I am missing some crucial maths here... and yeah it is not possible using CSS but there could be a workaround if you use `img` tag and give it effect as background.

Comment: Thought so I converted my project to an image tag and abso textarea but I'm really bother that I couldn't do this with CSS.

Comment: @BenRacicot ahh atlast I got it.. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/3gyc4atn/16/).

Comment: Hey awesome! Thanks so much for your effort. If i can ever help w anything please let me know @BenRacicot